# What would an android malware do with Direct Reply feature?

Tags: malware, android

I'm reading this article: https://research.nccgroup.com/2022/09/06/sharkbot-is-back-in-google-play/ and quote:

> Besides this, the dropper has also removed the ‘Direct Reply’ feature, used to automatically reply to the received notifications on the infected device. This is another feature which needs suspicious permissions, and which once removed makes it more difficult to detect.

I'm wondering what could the malware do with Direct Reply feature?

Comment: Did you perhaps link to the wrong article? I didn't find the quoted text on the Medium article about the Direct Reply tutorial.

Comment: Tracing the quoted text, looks like it's taken from https://blog.fox-it.com/2022/09/02/sharkbot-is-back-in-google-play/, which it refers to https://blog.fox-it.com/2022/03/03/sharkbot-a-new-generation-android-banking-trojan-being-distributed-on-google-play-store/ about the Direct Reply abuse and giving https://twitter.com/ThreatFabric/status/1486374206644367373 as the previous example.

Comment: @AndrewT. I pasted the wrong link: https://research.nccgroup.com/2022/09/06/sharkbot-is-back-in-google-play/

Comment: Direct reply in android is not protected by in-app authentication for user convenience. You can reply to a message without opening the app. A malware can send malicious links to the recipient or demand money.